# json request issue with newline (\n) in ios

Tags: json, afnetworking, newline

I am using afnetworking for json request, and I am passing string like "hello 
world". afnetworking json data converts it to "hello\\nworld". but php webservice getting it as "hello\nworld"(my json string). can any one give solution for it. please reply as soon as possible.
Thank you in advance.